# SSL/TLS: Policy Constraints vs. Basic Constraints

Tags: tls, certificates, public-key-infrastructure, x.509

Could someone please explain the difference between `Policy Constraints` and `Basic Constraints`?

It appears to me that they are either redundant, or two names for the same thing. I would love some clarification as Google searches aren't helping.

Comment: They're not the same thing. [`Basic constraints` are simple. Just two variables.](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5280#section-4.2.1.9) One that says CA/not-CA and one that limits pathlength. `Policy constraints` I don't know. [They're defined in the same RFC 5280](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5280#section-4.2.1.11), but I can only guess at the true usefulness of them. Maybe somebody else can shed light on that.

Comment: Per RFC5280

"The policy constraints extension can be used in certificates issued
   to CAs.  The policy constraints extension constrains path validation
   in two ways.  It can be used to prohibit policy mapping or require
   that each certificate in a path contain an acceptable policy
   identifier."  I don't understand what that means, but I found an example of it's use here [link](http://blogs.technet.com/b/pki/archive/2014/03/05/constraints-what-they-are-and-how-they-re-used-1.aspx) Could someone help me interperate?

Answer (score 10):

First, let's tackle "Basic Constraints" ([RFC 5280, Section 4.2.1.9](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.2.1.9)).  These are mostly for the sake of certificates issued for CAs.  RFC 5280 only defines two such "constraints":

- Are you (the *subject* of this certificate) a CA, yes or no?

This one is pretty straightforward.  A CA certificate, by definition, **must** have a basic constraints extension with this `cA` boolean value set to "true" in order to **be** a CA.

- Assuming you **are** a CA, how long of path of certificates can you issue?

This is the `pathLenConstraint` value, which is a number whose value is zero or greater.  Let's say I wanted to issue to you a CA certificate using my CA certificate, **but** I wanted to make sure you in turn could not use that CA certificate to issue *other* CA certificates.  I would add the basic constraints extension to your CA certificate, with the `cA` value of "true" *and* the `pathLenConstraint` value of "0".  `pathLenConstraint` is the number of "non-self-issued intermediate certificates" that could follow from your CA.  Note that the *end* certificate (usually a server or client certificate) does *not* count as part of this number.  So by using a `pathLenConstraint` of "0" in the CA certificate I issue to you, you can use that certificate to issue other *end* certificates, but **not** any intermediate certificates.  If no `pathLenConstraint` value is defined in the basic constraints extension, then no such limit is imposed.

Now, let's look at "Policy Constraints" ([RFC 5280, Section 4.2.1.11](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.2.1.11)).  The policy constraints extension, per RFC 5280, is for certificates that are issued to CAs; this extension is thus not really useful for end certificates (*e.g.* client/server certificates).  The RFC says that this extension is for constraining path validation to the CA in terms of "policies"; what then are these policies?

Understanding this requires that we look at [Certificate Policies](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.2.1.4), and [Policy Mappings](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.2.1.5).  A "certificate policy" is a fancy way of saying "I, as the CA organization, have some specific policy/terms; it is identified by this OID".  Thus each certificate policy has an OID, and usually some URI that points to more information about that policy.  RFC 5280 defines a "Certification Practice Statement" (CPS) certificate policy, for example, which contains a URI to the processing requirements of the CA (*e.g.* what their requirements are for getting a certificate issued by them).  I think of them as pointers to the terms of use/end user license agreement types of legalese.

Now, each different CA organization will have slightly (to *wildly*) different policies, *but* folks will ask a CA "how do your policy X relate to that other CA's policy Y?"  Especially when it comes to X509 cross signing (see [RFC 4158](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4158) for gory details).  Thus there is the need for a CA certificate to be able to say "my certificate policy X is equivalent to that certificate policy Y"; this is done using the policy mapping extension, which "maps" the OID of certificate policy X to the OID of certificate policy Y.

Now we have certificate policies, and we have mappings from one certificate policy to another.  The policy constraints extension, then, uses these to set limits/requirements, in terms of policies (and mappings of policies), when walking the list of certificates, from end certificate through the intermediate CAs to the root/trusted CA.  One of the limits, `inhibitPolicyMappings`, says "ignore any policy mappings after the Nth intermediate certificate in the path"; the other, `requireExplicitPolicy`, says "if there are more than N intermediate certificates in that path, require that all of them have X policy".

So, to sum up: basic constraints determine if you are a CA (`cA = true`), and if so, how long of a trust path can you create (limited by `pathLenConstraint`).  Policy constraints are all about **how** walking that trust path happens: how many of the intermediates certificates are allowed to have policy mappings, after which the policy mappings of intermediate certificates are ignored (`inhibitPolicyMapping = ...`), and/or how long can the trust path be, before a specific policy is required (`requireExplicitPolicy = ...`).

Back to that CA certificate I issued to you, whose `pathLenConstraint` basic constraint was set to zero.  That would prohibit you from issuing your own intermediate certificates.  And in that case, placing any policy constraints in that CA certificate would be rather useless, as policy constraints modify the handling of intermediate certificates (which you would be unable to issue/create).  Likewise, policy constraints on a non-CA certificate (and end certificate for a client/server) would be useless, for the same reason: they *cannot* issue/create intermediate certificates.

Now the above is all of the *theory*; for more information on the actual *reality* of all of this, in terms of implementations and such, I can highly recommend Peter Gutmann's materials on PKI, such as his [X509 Style Guide](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/%7Epgut001/pubs/x509guide.txt).

Hope this helps!